# Commerce plugin in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3

I am looking at Craft Commerce (https://craftcommerce.com/) and I am wondering if anyone has any experience using this in Craft 3? Seems like it is only for 2.x for now.  I am struggling to find any information on a Craft 3 release for Commerce.

Comment: Hi @laden, this question's probably better for Pixel & Tonic or the #craftcommerce Slack channel. Craft CMS meta is for discussion around how we're using and organizing the Craft CMS Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no release date for Craft 3 and it should not be used for projects at this time.

Answer (score 4):

We haven't given a hard date for the official release of Craft other than before the end of the year.

A Craft 3 compatible version of Commerce (Commerce 2.0) will be released at the same time Craft 3 is officially released.